# Can't use levenshtein() on a single array to compare and find elements with shortest distance

Tags: php, arrays, levenshtein-distance

Can't wrap my head around this one using levenshtein().

Lets say I have a array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Gammal URL] => /bil-och-garage
            [Ny URL] => /catalog/verktyg-och-maskiner
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Gammal URL] => /bil-och-garage/12-v-utrustning
            [Ny URL] => /catalog/verktyg-och-maskiner/handverktyg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Gammal URL] => /bil-och-garage/12-v-utrustning/antenn
            [Ny URL] => /catalog/verktyg-och-maskiner/handverktyg/slag-brytverktyg
        )
)
```

What I want to do is print the array but with a addition. What I want to do is go through the array and for each 'Gammal URL' do levenshtein() and find the 'Ny URL' with the shortest distance to the current 'Gammal URL'.

If there is no exact match (0), print the shortest one. I have been trying with different uses of foreach, nested, but cant wrap my head around how I can check 1 url agains the rest of the array one at a time.

In short, I want to print the whole array as above but a third column with the URL with the shortest distance. Any suggestions using two arrays is also welcomed if above is not the best solution.

**Edit**

With this i'm still getting wrong URL as "Matched URL" - any ideas?

```
foreach ($import as $key => $arr) {
      $shortest = '';
      foreach ($import as $key2 => $arr2) {
        if ($shortest != '') {
          // If the distance between the current Ny URL is shorted than the previously shortest one    :
          // -> it's the new shortest one, otherwise, I keep the previous one
          $shortest = (levenshtein($arr['Gammal URL'], $arr2['Ny URL']) < levenshtein($arr['Gammal   URL'], $shortest)) ? $arr2['Ny URL'] : $shortest;
        } else { // First attempt is set as the shortest aby default
          $shortest = $arr2['Ny URL'];
        }
      }
      // I found the shortest one for that Gammal URL
      $import[$key]['shortest'] = $shortest;

            echo'<tr>';
            echo'<td>'. $arr['Gammal URL']."</td>";
            echo'<td>'. $arr['Ny URL'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $shortest .'</td>';

    }
```

**Full code**

```
    <?php

//debug

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
?>


<?php

//import

function csv_import($filename='', $delimiter=';')
{
  if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;

  $header = NULL;
  $data = array();
  if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
  {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
      if(!$header)
        $header = $row;
      else
        $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
  return $data;
}

$import = csv_import('urler.csv');

//output

//print_r($import);

echo '<table>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo "<th>Gammal URL</th>";
echo "<th>Ny URL</th>";
echo "<th>Match URL</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "</tbody>";

foreach ($import as $key => $arr) {
  $shortest = '';

  foreach ($import as $key2 => $arr2) {
    if ($shortest != '') {
      // If the distance between the current Ny URL is shorted than the previously shortest one :
      // -> it's the new shortest one, otherwise, I keep the previous one
      $shortest = (levenshtein($arr['Gammal URL'], $arr2['Ny URL']) < levenshtein($arr['Gammal URL'], $shortest)) ? $arr2['Ny URL'] : $shortest;
    } else { // First attempt is set as the shortest aby default
      $shortest = $arr2['Ny URL'];
    }
  }
  // I found the shortest one for that Gammal URL
  $import[$key]['shortest'] = $shortest;


        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td>'. $arr['Gammal URL']."</td>";
        echo'<td>'. $arr['Ny URL'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'. $shortest .'</td>';

  }

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
  $shortest = '';
  foreach ($array as $key2 => $arr2) {
    if ($shortest != '') {
      // If the distance between the current Ny URL is shorted than the previously shortest one :
      // -> it's the new shortest one, otherwise, I keep the previous one
      $shortest = (levenshtein($arr['Gammal URL'], $arr2['Ny URL']) < levenshtein($arr['Gammal URL'], $shortest)) ? $arr2['Ny URL'] : $shortest;
    } else { // First attempt is set as the shortest by default
      $shortest = $arr2['Ny URL'];
    }
  }
  // I found the shortest one for that Gammal URL
  $array[$key]['shortest'] = $shortest;
}
```

I guess you wasn't too far since you had to nested foreach, but just ask in comment if you need anymore explanations

Comment: @Mikael Maybe `levenshtein` is not the function you're looking for then ? Can you give your current output, and the desired output ?

Comment: I can add that when the sample is small it works, but with a few more rows it breaks and it don't seem to choose the shortest distance.

Comment: @Mikael It's weird, really. This code isn't bound to any increment value or, it's just a comparison between the same function on different parameters

Comment: Well, use case is this: I need match 2700 old urls to a selection of 2000 news urls. The issue is that there is no distinct pattern between them other then some sections and some words are used in both the new and old urls. Meaning if old urls is dog/dogfood/puppyfood I need to match that with pets/animalfood/puppyfood or better. To my knowledge levenshetin() is the best fit. Input is a csv with 2 columns new and old urls. Output should be a table with same setup including a "Best match"-column where the best match new url matching the old.